# Get the average Hour period from a selected Date range

Tags: sql-server, date, average

I have a order table which happens to have a column of DataType "Datetime" which contains Date and Time of the arrival of product to the Company(customer) and i have multiple type of users 
their types are like: 
  Employee, CompanyOwners(customers),Dispatchers..etc

I have managed to get the date range of orders against to the specific user who is the owner of the company using the following T-SQL query below:

```
declare @username varchar(130), @DateFrom varchar(10), @DateTo varchar(10)
set @username = 'chabow';set @DateFrom='4/01/2018';set @DateTo='6/30/2018'
;with cte as (
    select count(o.ArrivalDate) as orders_count, cast(o.ArrivalDate as Date) as ArrivalDate
    from view_MembershipUsers msu
    inner join XrefCompanyUsers rfu on  msu.UserName = rfu.UserName
    inner join Company f on f.CompanyID = rfu.CompanyID
    inner join orders o on o.CompanyID = f.CompanyID
    where msu.UserName = @username and
    (o.ArrivalDate >= @DateFrom and  o.ArrivalDate <= @DateTo)
    group  by cast(o.ArrivalDate as Date)
    )
    select *,
    (select max(orders_count)+2 from  cte) as Total
    from cte    
    order by ArrivalDate
```

What i actually need to retrieve is the Average hour of arrival of product along with the data i have retrieved using above query from selected date range. I am clueless to how i can get the average in hours from this date range without getting the date difference, because i need to read "date" of every row to get the most possible accurate average hour.

I have extracted some sample dates for ease in order for you guys to help me.

```
create table SelectedData
(ArrivalDate date, ActualDateTime datetime)
insert into SelectedData values
('2018-04-01','2018-04-01 20:45:00.000'),
('2018-04-04','2018-04-04 19:00:00.000'),
('2018-04-05','2018-04-05 14:00:00.000'),
('2018-04-05','2018-04-05 14:23:00.000'),
('2018-04-05','2018-04-05 18:30:00.000'),
('2018-04-06','2018-04-06 12:30:00.000'),
('2018-04-06','2018-04-06 18:08:00.000')

declare @DateFrom varchar(10), @DateTo varchar(10)
    set @DateFrom='4/01/2018';set @DateTo='6/30/2018'

    select *
    from SelectedData   
    order by ArrivalDate
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You mentioned the type as Date, and this reflects the same in your code (ActualDateTime date), but then you insert with Date and time? Why is that Date, and not DateTime?

Comment: Data type "date" does not store time information, only the date part. You should use "datetime" or "smalldatetime"

Comment: edited  my bad and thanks for the notice. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your type to DateTime, and not date. Like this :

```
drop table SelectedData
create table SelectedData
(ArrivalDate date, ActualDateTime datetime)
insert into SelectedData values
('2018-04-01','2018-04-01 20:45:00.000'),
('2018-04-04','2018-04-04 19:00:00.000'),
('2018-04-05','2018-04-05 14:00:00.000'),
('2018-04-05','2018-04-05 14:23:00.000'),
('2018-04-05','2018-04-05 18:30:00.000'),
('2018-04-06','2018-04-06 12:30:00.000'),
('2018-04-06','2018-04-06 18:08:00.000')

declare @DateFrom varchar(10), @DateTo varchar(10)
set @DateFrom='4/01/2018';set @DateTo='6/30/2018'

select avg(datePart(hour, ActualDateTime))
from SelectedData   
--order by ArrivalDate
```

And then get the datepart of hours from the date, and then the average of that.

Comment: so it returns 16, can you please explain the answer that why it returns  16 what is the formula/calculation  - i asked in order to learn and gain knowledge about it. I'll really appreciate it bro. Thanks for the answer!!

Comment: There are two parts to this; the first one Datepart(part, date), gets a certain part of a date. In this instance, I extract the Hour part from ActualDateTime, which is an int. So now, we have a list of ints. Then, the second function, Avg, returns the average from a list of values, in this case, hours. So in essence, I'm saying .. get me all the hour parts of ActualDateTime. Cool. Now, for those, give me the average. Am I making sense?